# Automating Project Setup

Tags: notebooks

When starting a new project, at least for me, I like to dive right into it. As a result I will end up with a good chunk of code in some untitled notebook and eventually have to move files and set up a project directory. Can we automate this process so that setting up a new project is less troublesome?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Answer

Yes. The code at the bottom of this post does exactly that (at least on a Mac... in principal it should work for Windows and Linux. I have not tested this).

It's argument is simply the full path to the desired ProjectDirectory (which may or may not exist yet).

For example:

```
MakeProject[FileNameJoin[{Directory[], "Desktop", "StackExchangeDemo"}]]
```

If we call `NotebookDirectory[]`

```
NotebookDirectory[]
(*"/Users/Sumner/Desktop/StackExchangeDemo/"*)
```

The Notebook was saved with the same name as the ProjectDirectory.
Running `MakeProject` with the same arguments above, we see:

```
"Project Directory and Project Notebook appear to already
exist. Overwrite set to False. No actions taken."
```

## Explanation of Code

There are some things to note about the function below.
Foremost, by default, it will turn `NotebookAutoSave` on, i.e. every time you run an evaluation it will save the Notebook. You may or may not want this. So it is included as an option.

The logic implemented in the code considers the following

First we set two variables, `FileSavedQ`, which is set by whether or not the Notebook currently has "Untitled" in its Window, and `ProjectName` which is either the current name of the file (if it has been previously saved) or the same as the ProjectDirectory.

Then we implement the following If/Else tests:

- Does ProjectDirectory exist?

  - No? Make directory. Save Notebook.
  - Yes? Does file already exist?

    - Yes? May we overwrite?

      - Yes? Save.
      - No? Notify user.
    - No? Save.

(*NOTE:*) I do not test for your permissions. So if you try to write in a location that you do not have permission for, Mathematica will spit out a warning.

### UPDATE

Now includes option to make sub-folders. Running it with a already existent Directory will only add subfolders that previously do not exist.

```
MakeProject["/Users/Sumner/Desktop/test", "IncludeSubFolders" -> {"data", "images", "out", "log"}]
```

[image]

## Code

```
Options[MakeProject] = {"AutoSave" -> True, "Overwrite" -> False, 
   "IncludeSubFolders" -> {}};
MakeProject[ProjectDirectory_, OptionsPattern[]] := Module[
  {ProjectName, FileSavedQ},
  (*Get Boole for whether or not file already is saved. 
  Based off whether or not file name has "Untitled" in it*)

  FileSavedQ = 
   Options[NotebookInformation[], WindowTitle] // First // 
     Last // ! StringContainsQ[#, "Untitled"] &;

  (*If has name, retrieve it. If not, 
  set to the ProjectDirectory's name*)
  If[FileSavedQ,
   ProjectName = 
    Options[NotebookInformation[], WindowTitle] // First // Last // 
     FileBaseName,
   ProjectName = Last@FileNameSplit@ProjectDirectory
   ];

  (*Test for non-existence of Project Directory*)

  If[! DirectoryQ[ProjectDirectory],

   (*Directory does not exist. Easy. 
   We create the Directory and save our file.*)

   CreateDirectory[ProjectDirectory];
   NotebookSave[EvaluationNotebook[], 
    FileNameJoin[{ProjectDirectory, ProjectName <> ".nb"}]];
   SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], 
    NotebookAutoSave -> OptionValue[MakeProject, "AutoSave"]];

   (*Make subfolders*)

   With[{subfolders = OptionValue[MakeProject, "IncludeSubFolders"]},
    If[Length@subfolders > 0,
      Table[
        CreateDirectory[
         FileNameJoin[{ProjectDirectory, 
           subfolders[[folder]]}]], {folder, Length@subfolders}];
      ];
    ];
   ,


   (*Directory does exist. 
   We must test for whether or not file already exists.*)

   If[! FileExistsQ[
      FileNameJoin[{ProjectDirectory, ProjectName <> ".nb"}]],
    (*File does not exist. Easy. Save file.*)

    NotebookSave[EvaluationNotebook[], 
     FileNameJoin[{ProjectDirectory, ProjectName <> ".nb"}]];
    SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], 
     NotebookAutoSave -> OptionValue[MakeProject, "AutoSave"]];,

    (*File does exist. May we overwrite?*)

    If[ OptionValue[MakeProject, "Overwrite"],
      (*May we overwrite? Yes. Save file*)

      NotebookSave[EvaluationNotebook[], 
       FileNameJoin[{ProjectDirectory, ProjectName <> ".nb"}]];
      SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], 
       NotebookAutoSave -> OptionValue[MakeProject, "AutoSave"]];,
      (*May we overwrite? No. Notify user*)

      Print[
        "Project Directory and Project Notebook appear to already 
exist. Overwrite set to False. No actions taken."];

      ];


    ];

   (*Make subfolders that do not already exist*)

   With[{subfolders = OptionValue[MakeProject, "IncludeSubFolders"]},
    If[Length@subfolders > 0,
      Table[
        If[! 
          DirectoryQ[
           FileNameJoin[{ProjectDirectory, subfolders[[folder]]}]],
         CreateDirectory[
          FileNameJoin[{ProjectDirectory, subfolders[[folder]]}]]
         ], {folder, Length@subfolders}
        ];
      ];
    ];


   ];
  ]
```